# How to register a destructor for a C-allocated numpy array?

Tags: python, c, numpy

I want to allocate numbers for a numpy array in C/C++, and pass them to python as a numpy array. That I can do with [PyArray_SimpleNewFromData](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_SimpleNewFromData).

The problem is that I also want to register a function that should be invoked from Python when the numpy array reference counter reaches zero, and that would invoke some destructor semantics on the C side... Here is a pseudo-example of what I need:

```
 float* arr; PyObject* np_arr; void (*destructor)(float* arr);
 // ... C-allocate array on arr, ...
 // ...
 // ... initialize destructor with some suitable value, and then:
 np_arr = /* ... create the array to wrap arr, 
             and to use destructor on some meaningful way ... */
```

is there a simple way of doing so?

Comment: There is not a simple way as such however I think this URL will answer your question http://blog.enthought.com/python/numpy-arrays-with-pre-allocated-memory/

Answer (score 9):

The idea is to create a Python object that knows how to free your memory when destroyed and make it the base of the returned C-allocated numpy array. This sounds tricky but it can be easily achieved via something known as [capsules](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/capsule.html) in python. Let me give an example,

Suppose that you have the following code,

```
PyObject *arr;
int nd = 2;
npy_intp dims[] = {5, 10};
double *data = some_function_that_returns_a_double_star(x, y, z);

arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void *)data);
return arr;
```

There is an obvious memory leak here since you cannot free data until arr is deleted as it says [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_New) in the red warning box. Fixing this, on the other hand, is easy. Define a function which is basically a destructor function that knows how to do garbage collection.

```
void capsule_cleanup(PyObject *capsule) {
    void *memory = PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, NULL);
    // Use your specific gc implementation in place of free if you have to
    free(memory);
}
```

Now augment your code as,

```
PyObject *arr;
int nd = 2;
npy_intp dims[] = {5, 10};
double *data = some_function_that_returns_a_double_star(x, y, z);

arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(nd, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, (void *)data);
PyObject *capsule = PyCapsule_New(data, NULL, capsule_cleanup);
// NULL can be a string but use the same string while calling PyCapsule_GetPointer inside capsule_cleanup
PyArray_SetBaseObject((PyArrayObject *) arr, capsule);
return arr;
```

There is no need to `Py_DECREF` the capsule. The function `PyArray_SetBaseObject` steals reference.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But why the destructor is not called after the program ends? I put a printf inside capsule_cleanup and nothing printed :(