# What is the correct type for PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()'s dims argument?

Tags: python, c, numpy-ndarray

the numpy C API documentation gives this signature:

```
PyObject* PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(int nd, npy_intp* dims, int typenum, void *data)
```

Note that dims is essentially of type int**. However, all examples I found for the usage of this and similar functions pass type int*, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357115/pyarray-simplenewfromdata-example).

When passing a pointer to integer my code works fine, but the compiler complains about pointer type mismatch of the "dims" argument.

```
PyObject *arr;

import_array();

npy_float d[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
npy_intp dims[] = {sizeof d / sizeof *d};
arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_FLOAT, d);
```

From my understanding of how the function works, I believe int* should be the right type because it is just an input parameter that informs the function about how many entries each array dimension has. I don't understand why both the documentation and the compiler expect int** event though int* works.

So how is it done right?

Comment: Maybe tag this with [tag:C] as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion seems to stem from a misunderstanding of what `npy_intp` is. It's not a typedef for `int *`. It's an *integer* type big enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: Thanks! I pored over numpy's deeply nested header files to find out what npy_intp was ind it looked like a pointer to int. Of course i COULD have looked it up in the docs, but where is the fun in that?